# How to filter out non duplicates in a list in scala?

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, higher-order-functions

I was wondering what would be the scala way to filter our only the values, which are not duplicate in Scala?

Lets say for instance that I have this list:

```
val l = List(1,1,2,3,4,5,5)
```

I want the result to be :

```
List(2,3,4)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you find any problem during your solution? BTW, look a `groupBy`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
val l = List(1,1,2,3,4,5,5)

val res = l.groupBy(identity).filterNot(_._2.size > 1).keys.toList
// List(2,3,4)
```

Here I am grouping by itself, then filter out if the values have more than 1 occurrence retrieving the keys and casting it to a List.

Hope it helps.